# Swift Extension and 'Element' explicit initialization

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I wonder if is there any other way to explicitly initialize an Element object in a Swift extension ?

For example I would like to do this but non-nominal type 'Element' does not support explicit initialization

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func findDuplicate() -> Int {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return -1 }
        let sum = self.reduce(0, +)
        let expectedSum = Element((self.count - 1) * self.count / 2)
        return sum - expectedSum
    }
}
```

Of course if I remove the forced Element casting in the expectedSum assignment and let the compiler use an Int I obtain an error comparing sum (Element) and expectedSum (Int)

I can easily have my extension working with where Element == Int but of course this is no more generic in this way.

Any hints?

Comment: First don't use the count property to check if your array is empty. Second make the return type optional instead of returning -1. Btw What is your method supposed to do?

Comment: Whats is the purpose of making it generic if you are returning Int. Return the `Element?` and use `BinaryInteger` or `FloatingPoint` instead of `Numeric`

Comment: It's very unclear how the above algorithm implements "find duplicate." What is the meaning of the return value? Why is it an integer (how is that "the duplicate")?  What do you mean by "explicitly initialize" in this case? `Numeric` includes `init?(exactly:)` for converting from any `BinaryInteger` (and `count` is always `Int`, so that applies). But it's very unclear what you mean this code to do.

Comment: @RobNapier: Probably a task like *"You have an array of n numbers from 1 to n-1, where exactly one of the numbers occurs twice. Find the duplicate element.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion of an integer to a `Numeric` type is done with [`init?(exactly:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric/2886795-init). Taking Leo's suggestions into account:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func findDuplicate() -> Element? {
        guard !isEmpty else { return nil }
        let sum = self.reduce(0, +)
        guard let expectedSum = Element(exactly: (count - 1) * count / 2) else { return nil }
        return sum - expectedSum
    }
}
```

On the other hand, this seems to be a programming task that
is specifically about *integers,* and then it might make more sense
to restrict the element type to `BinaryInteger` (and use `Int`
for the intermediate calculations to avoid overflow):

```
extension Array where Element: BinaryInteger {
    func findDuplicate() -> Element? {
        guard !isEmpty else { return nil }
        let sum = Int(reduce(0, +))
        let expectedSum = (count - 1) * count / 2
        return Element(sum - expectedSum)
    }
}
```

or even `Element == Int`.

Comment: Thank you MartinR, Element(exactly: ) is what I was looking for.  Btw I agree with any comments above, the "find duplicate in a array of n numbers + 1" code was just a quick way to explain my problem.  @LeoDabus the method only work in that particular scenarios where you have a random ordered array of 1...n values plus a duplicate.  Once again it was just a quick example to explain the usage of Element explicit initialization in a Extension.